# Script for getting the tab/sheet name not working in google spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have following google spreadsheet bound script whose job is to create copy of the 'template' sheet whenever there is data in the A:A column of the 1st Sheet ('Projects').

This script was working absolutely fine. However, later I have added a line of code with this script (the last line of the code in the script below) intending to extract and put the newly created sheet's name in one of its cell - J2.

Somehow that line of code is not working while the rest of the code does its job properly. Any suggestion on this would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

```
function onOpen() {
  var menu = [{
        name : "Add",
        functionName : "newSheet"
    }];
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().addMenu("Sheet", menu);
}

function newSheet() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var templateSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Template");
  var sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName("Projects")
  var getNames = sheet1.getRange("A:A").getValues().filter(String).toString().split(",");

for (var i = 0; i < getNames.length; i++) {
    var copy = ss.getSheetByName(getNames[i]);
    if (copy) {
        Logger.log("Sheet already exists");
    } else {
        templateSheet.copyTo(ss).setName(getNames[i]);
        ss.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheetByName(getNames[i]));
        ss.moveActiveSheet(ss.getNumSheets());

  ss.getSheetByName(getNames[i]).copyTo(ss.getSheetByName(getNames[i]).getRange("J2"));
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to GAS documentation, the copyTo() method of the Sheet class only accepts Spreadsheet instances as parameters. It doesn't work because you are passing Range as parameter. Also, getSheetByName() returns the Sheet object, so you aren't actually copying the name of the sheet.

If you'd like to modify specific range, it's much more convenient to use Range instead.

```
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(getNames[i]);
var cell = sheet.getRange("J2");
cell.setValue(getNames[i]); // writing the name of the sheet to cell J2
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Anton!